# Get column name from where condition in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying below:

I am trying to process where condition of sql in java. How can I get column name in where condition as a string ?

```
Ex: String s = "Name_id>=11"
```

now I want to get "Name_id", as it is a column name and i want to do processing on it.

I know it can be done using regex but I am new to regex and don't know how to do it. can someone guide me??
help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Have you even tried reading a regex tutorial or any relevant documentation? Or do you expect us to just give you the answer? You'll appreciate the help more if it comes from you.

Comment: What would you do if the variable holding the condition contains multiple conditions?

Comment: I just want to know how to get data if particular condition in regex matches. In this example i will do pattern matching for ">=" but how to get everything before this pattern is a problem for me.
Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?...you can make SQL queries to return exactly what you want.

Comment: There are __numerous__ examples of getting a string before a pattern.  Attempt something and come back if you have problems.

Comment: @devnull : Its the next step for me, let me try for 1 condition first :) T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
s = s.replaceAll("^(\\w+).+", "$1");
```